# How to add a new page in CKAN?

Tags: python, postgresql, pylons, ckan, opendata

I'm using CKAN as my open data portal. It's written in Python using Pylons framework. It uses Postgres as the database. I just want to add a new page similar to about page to display the terms and conditions to the users. About page comes built in.

*Given that it would be better if I can edit the page content from the admin area like the about page. If it's more work/development I could ignore it. I just want the simplest way to get this done. It would be really nice if you could explain the answer a bit. At least the steps.*

**How can I add a new page in CKAN?**

Answer (score 10, accepted):

If you want yourself or non-technical admins to be able to add simple static pages and blogs and edit their contents, I recommend installing the [ckanext-pages extension](https://github.com/ckan/ckanext-pages).

It's also possible to write your own CKAN plugin that adds some static pages, though if you're going to go as far as web forms for editing them then you may as well use the pages extension above, but see for example [ckanext-sa](https://github.com/okfn/ckanext-sa) for an example of how to add some simple static pages from a plugin.

To install the pages extension:

```
# Activate your CKAN virtual environment
. /usr/lib/ckan/default/bin/activate

# Install the pages extension.
pip install -e 'git+https://github.com/ckan/ckanext-pages.git#egg=ckanext-pages'
```

Then add `pages` to the `ckan.plugins` setting in your CKAN config file, and restart your web server. When logged into CKAN as a sysadmin user, you should see the pages button in the top right.